# Typescript and Koa BaseContext Issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa

Typescript throws the error message that request does not exist in the type BaseContext. That can't be because I've used the code before and it worked.

> Property 'request' does not exist on type 'BaseContext'.

```
import { BaseContext } from 'koa'



export function handle(ctx: BaseContext) {
    ctx.body = ctx.request.body
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "env/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a quick look at the actual types here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa/index.d.ts

It kinda looks like these properties don't exist on `BaseContext`. It also does seem like some changes were recently made to this.

I might be mistaken, but I believe the correct type to use is `Context`, not `BaseContext`. This has at least always worked for me.

Comment: I have used `const file = ctx.request.file` to get a file with multer before. How can I do this now?
When I add // @ts-ignore I am able to run the code.

Comment: I don't know what adds the `file` property, but it's not in the base Koa interface. It's possible that it worked before if the Context object previous was typed as any, but I'm not certain.

Comment: For a single file it is ctx.file. Thanks for help!

Comment: the api changed after some koa version